# Is it normal for Mac to make startup sound every morning?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, power-management

If I'm not using it, about 8:00 every morning my sleeping MacBook Pro (with lid shut) makes a starting up sound (the sound of the hardware, not any system sound). I guess it wakes up by itself.

What could be the cause of this?

This is the pmset log:

```
2019-03-30 07:55:05 -0700 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [en0 driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 2)(540 ms)]
2019-03-30 07:55:05 -0700 Assertions            PID 71(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "Holding in darkwake for up to 30 seconds to update inactivity prediction" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00008e25 [System: PrevIdle SRPrevSleep kCPU]
2019-03-30 07:55:05 -0700 DarkWake              DarkWake from Standby [CDN] due to RTC/SleepService: Using BATT (Charge:94%) 2 secs
2019-03-30 07:55:05 -0700 HibernateStats        hibmode=3 standbydelay=4200                                                           rd=392 ms
2019-03-30 07:55:05 -0700 WakeTime              WakeTime: 6.275 sec
2019-03-30 07:55:06 -0700 Assertions            PID 98(timed) Released NoIdleSleepAssertion "com.apple.timed.ntp" 06:53:26  id:0x0x100008e23 [System: SRPrevSleep kCPU]
2019-03-30 07:55:06 -0700 Assertions            PID 368(mds_stores) Released BackgroundTask "com.apple.metadata.mds_stores.power" 06:53:26  id:0x0xb00008e24 [System: PrevIdle SRPrevSleep kCPU]
2019-03-30 07:55:06 -0700 Assertions            PID 14954(diskmanagementd) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.diskmanagementd" 06:53:27  id:0x0x100008e22 [System: PrevIdle SRPrevSleep kCPU]
2019-03-30 07:55:06 -0700 Assertions            PID 216(mDNSResponder) Created MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00008e27 [System: PrevIdle SRPrevSleep kCPU]
2019-03-30 07:55:06 -0700 Assertions            PID 216(mDNSResponder) Released MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00008e27 [System: PrevIdle SRPrevSleep kCPU]
2019-03-30 07:55:06 -0700 Assertions            Kernel Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler
2019-03-30 07:55:06 -0700 Notification          Display is turned on
2019-03-30 07:55:07 -0700 Notification          Next largest inactivity window start:'2019-03-30 23:45:00 -0700' end:'2019-03-31 08:30:00 -0700'
2019-03-30 07:55:07 -0700 Assertions            PID 71(powerd) Released InternalPreventSleep "Holding in darkwake for up to 30 seconds to update inactivity prediction" 00:00:01  id:0x0xd00008e25 [System: No Assertions]
2019-03-30 07:55:07 -0700 Wake                  DarkWake to FullWake from Standby [CDNVA] due to HID Activity: Using BATT (Charge:93%)
2019-03-30 07:55:07 -0700 HibernateStats        hibmode=3 standbydelay=4200                                                           rd=392 ms
2019-03-30 07:55:07 -0700 WakeTime              WakeTime: 0.454 sec
2019-03-30 07:55:07 -0700 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [AppleHDAHDMI_DPDriver driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(405 ms)] [AppleHDADriver driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(442 ms)]
2019-03-30 07:55:07 -0700 WakeTime              WakeTime: 0.454 sec
```

These are the power settings:

```
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 standbydelaylow      4200
 standby              1
 womp                 1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 sms                  1
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            10
 standbydelayhigh     4200
 sleep                10 (sleep prevented by storeassetd, storeassetd, storeassetd, storeassetd, storeassetd)
 autopoweroffdelay    14400
 hibernatemode        3
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         10
 highstandbythreshold 50
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

Comment: Well, it’s certainly not normal, this is super bizarre!

Comment: Does this happen when your MacBook Pro is both plugged in and running on battery?

Comment: How do you know it’s not starting up on schedule from energy saver?

Comment: @jmh ,I don't recall if it happens when plugged in. I normally never shut it off, but I unplug and close the lid to let it sleep.

Comment: @bmike, my energy saver settings are set at the default settings.

Comment: Yes - but how do you _know_ instead of guess. Have a look at `pmset` and console questions on the sleep wake tab here. Maybe we just need to explain how to read the other log files? (Or are you asking someone to help design a camera situation so you can record this. It seems you can predict the timing quite well.

Comment: Thanks @bmike, I'll edit the question to show the log results.